# How to split a text file content by a string?

Tags: bash

Suppose I've got a text file that consists of two parts separated by delimiting string `---`

```
aa
bbb
---
cccc
dd
```

I am writing a bash script to read the file and assign the first part to var `part1` and the second part to var `part2`:

```
part1= ... # should be aa\nbbb
part2= ... # should be cccc\ndd
```

How would you suggest write this in bash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
foo="$(awk 'NR==1' RS='---\n' ORS='' file.txt)"
bar="$(awk 'NR==2' RS='---\n' ORS='' file.txt)"
```

This would read the file twice, but handling text files in the shell, i.e. storing their content in variables should generally be limited to small files. Given that your file *is* small, this shouldn't be a problem.

Note: Depending on your actual task, you may be able to just use `awk` for the whole thing. Then you don't need to store the content in shell variables, and read the file twice.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking about doing "the entire thing" in `awk` but still not sure ...

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `sed`:

```
foo=$(sed '/^---$/q;p' -n file.txt)
bar=$(sed '1,/^---$/b;p' -n file.txt)
```

The `-n` command line option tells `sed` to not print the input lines as it processes them (by default it prints them). `sed` runs a script for each input line it processes.

The first `sed` script

```
/^---$/q;p
```

contains two commands (separated by `;`):

- `/^---$/q` - quit when you reach the line matching the regex `^---$` (a line that contains exactly three dashes);
- `p` - print the current line.

The second `sed` script

```
1,/^---$/b;p
```

contains two commands:

- `1,/^---$/b` - starting with line `1` until the first line matching the regex `^---$` (a line that contains only `---`), branch to the end of the script (i.e. skip the second command);
- `p` - print the current line;

Answer (score 1):

Using `csplit`:

`csplit --elide-empty-files --quiet --prefix=foo_bar file.txt "/---/" "{*}" && sed -i '/---/d' foo_bar*`

If version of `coreutils >= 8.22`, `--suppress-matched` option can be used and `sed` processing is not required, like

`csplit --suppress-matched --elide-empty-files --quiet --prefix=foo_bar file.txt "/---/" "{*}"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never heard of `csplit`.

Comment: @Michael, Welcome! `csplit` is a [GNU utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html)